# How To ALTER New Columns In Table by Items from ListBox

Tags: vba, vb.net, multiple-columns, alter

I Have Database worked perfect in MS Access 2010 with code that ALTER New Fields in Table all that from `ListBox` items that filling from another table by user code below:

```
Sub AlterTableX()
   Dim intLoop As Integer
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim strSQL1 As String
   For intLoop = 0 To Me.field_row.ListCount - 1
   strSQL = "ALTER TABLE Emp_Sal ADD " & _
   Me.field_row.Column(0, [intLoop]) & "  LONG INTEGER"
   CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
   strSQL1 = "ALTER TABLE tbl_General ADD " & _
   Me.field_row.Column(0, [intLoop]) & "  LONG INTEGER"
   CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL1
   Next intLoop
'  MsgBox "Success Adding Columns", vbOKOnly, "Success"
End Sub
```

Well, Now I want to convert that VBA code to VB.NET 2012

I want your help.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence. Please fix the grammar. I don't see what exactly your question is.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  So you're wanting to issue these alter table commands in `VB.NET` instead of Access directly?  You'll need an [oledbcommand](http://www.functionx.com/vbnet/oledb/Lesson02.htm) object!

Comment: I want alter two tables named Emp_sal & tbl_General  with all items from listbox field_row that filling by user as columns

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code. Any errors?

Comment: Your are going to have to learn ADO.net. Broad subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to execute the same commands in VB.NET, then try something like this.  It should get you started but best you read up on ADO.NET as sugested in comments

```
    Using SqlCMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
        SqlCMD.Connection = CurrentProject.Connection
        Try
            SqlCMD.Connection.Open()
            For intLoop As Integer = 0 To Me.field_row.ListCount - 1
                SqlCMD.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE Emp_Sal ADD " & Me.field_row.Column(0, [intLoop]) & "  LONG INTEGER"
                SqlCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
                SqlCMD.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE tbl_General ADD " & Me.field_row.Column(0, [intLoop]) & "  LONG INTEGER"
                SqlCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR ALTERING TABLE")
        Finally
            SqlCMD.Connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
```